# Javascript receives ActiveX event only once

Tags: javascript, c++, events, activex

I've written an ActiveX control using ATL. I used the wizard to add support for connection points which added `public IConnectionPointContainerImpl<CActiveX>` and `CProxy_IActiveXEvents<CActiveX>`, where the `CProxy_...` is the wizard generated code to fire events.

I've defined a dispinterface as follows:

> [
>           uuid(43ECB3DF-F004-4FAD-9BFB-79211A693C3A),
>           helpstring("ActiveX Events")
>       ]
>       dispinterface _IActiveXEvents
>       {
>           properties:
>           methods:
>               [id(1)] void receiveCertificate([in] VARIANT_BOOL isPermissionGranted, [in] BSTR certificateXml);
>       };

and included it in the coclass with `[default,source] dispinterface _IActiveXEvents`. To fire the event I call `Fire_receiveCertificate(isGranted, _bstr_t(certXml.c_str()).copy())`, which is defined in the wizard-code.

The following Javascript will receive the event

> ```
> function ActiveXObject::receiveCertificate(permission, certificate) {
>       alert("alert!");
>   }
> ```

The problem is it only receives the event once, and I have to close and reopen IE to get it to receive the event again. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I found the solution to this problem. I had registered the object in the ROT (running object table), but was not revoking any previously existing registrations. Thus, multiple registrations were appearing. Once I ensured I revoked previous registrations, events fired reliably.